# What is the AutoFac equivalent of the Unity liftetime HierarchicalLifetimeManager?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, autofac, unity-container

I am attempting to convert the below unity container registration into an AutoFac container

```
container.RegisterType<C1Context>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
container.RegisterFactory<I1CallContext>(c => c.Resolve<C1Context>());
container.RegisterFactory<I2CallContext>(c => c.Resolve<C1Context>());
```

I got as close as the below in autofac:

```
container.RegisterType<C1Context>()
    .As<I1CallContext, I2CallContext>()
    .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

The components are registered as expected, however the lifetime does not seem to match up with Unity - have I configured this incorrectly? I have tried many different implementations with no luck.

Comment: AFAICT what you are doing seems correct: you are registering the type C1Context to be resolved once per LifetimeScope. In each nested scope you have, only 1 C1Context will be instantiated, and provided to anyone requiring a I2CallContext or a I1CallContext. Are you sure you are nesting the Autofac LifetimeScopes in the same way you are nesting the Unity containers? Sorry for not being specific, but I don't know Unity, only Autofac.

Comment: I don't actually generate any additional scopes other than the main container instance - I'm just trying to ensure it behaves as closely to the existing code as possible to avoid any issues but it doesn't seem to be playing ball!

Comment: If you don't generate any additional scopes, what do you mean with "doesn't work"? What does "work" means in your case? Probably you should be a little more specific: as it stands, your question does not describe any problem.

Comment: It does not behave in the same way it worked with the unity equivalent, the lifecycle of the object must be different as the properties become null where they were not prior.

Comment: I would try to log the construction of C1Context. I suspect you have some scoping (maybe unintended) going on (some `using(var scope = containerOrScope.BeginLifetimeScope())` around). If you have only one scope you should have only one `C1Context` instance. If you don't, it seems you have multiple scopes. If previously it worked differently, you need to match the previous nesting of Containers with the nesting of LifetimeScopes. There lies the problem, IMHO.